# parallax snap to scrollTop()

Tags: parallax, snapping

i'm trying parallaxa site to snap to certain point.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 6500 && $(this).scrollTop() > 7500 ) {
    $(this).scrollTop(7000);
}
```

But with these code the snapping occures even, when i wanna move out from area.
How to fix this?